# Исключение работает не верно

Tags: java

Код выкидывает исключение, но по идее не должен. Исключение написано мной. Проверка на формат файла. Если нетекстовый формат, то должно выбрасываться исключение. А там стоит верный формат, но исключение выбрасывается. Помогите разобраться.

```
try {
    String name = "C:\\Users\\Neizvestnost\\Desktop\\Test.txt";
    IncorrectFormat i = new IncorrectFormat();
    name = name.substring( name.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    if(name !="txt") throw new IncorrectFormat();

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Neizvestnost\\Desktop\\Test.txt"));
} catch (IncorrectFormat e ) {
    System.out.println("некоректный форма");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Нету такого");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте вместо name новую переменную, так как в Java строки остаются неизменными. Так же для сравнения строк используется метод equals(), так как строки объекты, используя = вы сравниваете ссылки на объекты.

Что написано у вас:

```
name = name.substring( name.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
if(name !="txt") throw new IncorrectFormat();
```

Измените на это.

```
String name2 = name.substring( name.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
if(!name2.equals("txt")) throw new IncorrectFormat();
```

Comment: Введение новой переменной излишне. Достаточно перейти к !equals().